# Pausing execution in C#

Tags: c#

I have a program that I would like to display a text, wait 2 seconds, then exit. When I run it, it waits two seconds and exits, but does not display the text.

Code:

```
if (userNumber == selectedNumber)
{
    userMSGLabel.Text = "You guessed the correct number. Program is exiting";
    userMSGLabel.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Environment.Exit(-1);
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You could try adding an `Application.DoEvents` before your `Thread.Sleep` call which will render your screen before putting the thread to sleep.  Otherwise, I'd just use a timer as suggested by the answers below for the reasons they outlined :)

Comment: Why are you using `Environment.Exit` to end the program? Can't you just call the main form's `Close` method?

Comment: @JimMischel -- He probably has to use `Environment.Exit` if he needs a custom return code, like `-1`.

Comment: @icemanind: There are other ways to do that. For example, just set [Environment.ExitCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exitcode.aspx), and then call the `Close` method.

Answer (score 3):

I think your `Thread.Sleep(2000)` is blocking the UI thread. Please try

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "You guessed the correct number. Program is exiting";
    label1.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(Sleep).ContinueWith(t => Exit());
}

private void Sleep()
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}

private void Exit()
{
    Environment.Exit(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a timer instead of thread.sleep. I can't tell from your code, but you are probably in the GUI thread, which is preventing the screen from being redrawn.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.Sleep` blocks the current thread for the specified time, and you’re in the UI thread, which is used to update labels. The easiest way to change this is probably to add a timer control (you appear to be using Windows Forms) with an `Interval` of 2000:

```
private void CloseTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Environment.Exit(-1); // Can’t you just use Close() or something?
}
```

and instead of sleeping and exiting,

```
CloseTimer.Start();
```

In general, you can also start another thread in one of several other ways, including but not limited to:

- [Using thread pool threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1419378/707111)
- [Using `System.Timers` timers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8496430/707111)
- Using full threads:

  ```
  Thread t = new Thread(delegate {
      Thread.Sleep(2000);
      Environment.Exit(-1);
  });

  t.Start();
  ```
- Using tasks, as @Max writes; this is particularly nice
- Using `Application.DoEvents` (but don’t; it’s evil, and your UI will still lock up, just with a correct label; doing it in a loop is redundant; use one of the other things)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Application.DoEvents()` to request Windows to repaint your label.

```
if (userNumber == selectedNumber)
{
    userMSGLabel.Text = "You guessed the correct number. Program is exiting";
    userMSGLabel.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
    Application.DoEvents();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Environment.Exit(-1);
}
```